# Is there any non-linear optimization technique whose running time depends on the diameter of the underlying polytope(induced by constraints)

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

It is well known that the running time of the simplex algorithm depends on the diameter of the polytope induced by the constraints. Is there any non-linear optimization technique that also has this property ?

Comment: Diameter as measured how? Couldn't you just scale up any polytope?

Comment: Hi @Bey Actually diameter in the sense of "Diameter of Graph" =  max of $\{$the minimum number of edges needed to reach any vertex by a path from any other vertex$\}$

Comment: Isn't that running time claim for LP based on the ellipsoid method? And can't the ellipsoid method be applied to any convex model (even nonlinear) that admits a cutting plane oracle?